# Linux (Ubuntu/Linuxmint) crashes with scattered screen

Tags: linux, graphics, crash, wayland

I have a repeating problem with linux on my company laptop. From time to time (totally unexpected) my linux crashes with a scattered screen and audio loop. I couldn't find any other log as in /var/crash/.
I had the same problem before on Linux Mint where my home folder was encrypted, so I re-installed the whole system to Ubuntu wiping out the whole SSD but the problem still remains.
On the other SSD there is Windows 10 which works perfectly. Even our company technician tried some serious test on the Windows keeping the system load on max for several hours but couldn't reproduce the error.

My laptop: HP ProBook 450 G7 i7-10510U 15.6 FHD UWVA 250HD, 2x16GB, SSD 512GB NVMe (PCIe)(Windows) + 512GB Samsung SATA SSD (linux system), FpS, ax, BT, Backlit kbd, Win10

[image of the scattered screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8h37.jpg)

only log I found:
[log](http://upload.ketyi.com/_usr_bin_Xwayland.125.crash)

Thank you for any clue helping me investigate the problem.

Comment: Given the screenshot, it looks like a video driver problem.  Please specify the video hardware on this system.  (Try  `lspci | grep -i 'vga\|graphics'`)

Comment: 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)

Comment: Well this is still on, today my laptop crashed twice without any logs. Also in the folder /var/crash the only thing I have is kexec_cmd. Anyone any clue about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was with the kernel itself. After several hours of googling I found out that there is a bug in the 5.4 kernel which regarding my source is not fixed in 5.5 but an update note on the bottom says it **does**
source: https://linuxreviews.org/Linux_Kernel_5.5_Will_Not_Fix_The_Frequent_Intel_GPU_Hangs_In_Recent_Kernels

3 days ago I have updated my linux kernel to 5.5 (5.5.0-050500-generic) and from that point I had no freezes so far.

Hope this helps to others with same issue out there.